Flutter app - can't run local web app (with local web server) on local ip
i have some flutter app. i can run (on MacOs) it web server with fvm flutter run -t lib/main_develop_web.dart -d web-server --web-hostname 127.0.0.1 --web-port 64000. And in Safari i can run it at address 127.0.0.1:64000 - that is ok. When i try run it with my local ip(192.168.1.224) - fvm flutter run -t lib/main_develop_web.dart -d web-server --web-hostname 192.168.1.224 --web-port 64000 and 192.168.1.224:64000 i see that index.html run, but after that blank page.
In Safari console i see:
Exception while loading service worker:
Error: Service Worker API unavailable. The current context is NOT secure. Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts
loadServiceWorker — flutter.js:3:109
(anonymous function) — flutter.js:3:2477
loadEntrypoint — flutter.js:3:2693
(anonymous function) — 192.168.1.224:141

with "python3 -m http.server 64000" - same problem
What am i doing wrong?
